# override using .groups argument

Tags: r, group-by, mean

I keep getting "`summarise()` has grouped output by 'new_brand'. You can override using
the `.groups` argument." I'm not sure if I'm getting this error because I created columns pos_prop and neg_prop

```
superbowl %>% group_by(new_brand, superbowl) %>% summarize(mean(superbowl$volume, superbowl$pos_prop, superbowl$neg_prop), sd(superbowl$volume, superbowl$pos_prop, superbowl$neg_prop)) %>% filter(superbowl, superbowl == "0")
```

When I run `rlang::last_error()` The code works, I'm not sure how to make the code run properly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: (1) That's not an error. You could use `.groups` with several options to keep or drop the grouping. If you are satisfied with the current grouping, just ignore this message or use `.groups = "keep" or `.groups = "drop_last". (2) In `summarise` you either assign a new column or apply a function an several columns using `across`. You do neither of those options.

Comment: This isn't an error; it's more like a 'hey, by the way...'. Did you get the outcome you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `summarize` and such incorrectly. Try this:

```r
superbowl %>%
  group_by(new_brand) %>%
  summarize(across(c(volume, pos_prop, neg_prop),
                   list(mu = ~ mean(.), sigma = ~ sd(.)))) %>%
  filter(superbowl == "0")
```

Notes on your code:

- once you start a `dplyr`-pipe with `superbowl %>%`, almost *never* use `superbowl$` in the dplyr verbs (very rare exceptions); I also removed references to `superbowl` in both `group_by` and `filter`, since it is not clear if you're trying to refer to the original frame symbol again ... if you have `superbowl$superbowl`, then they may still be appropriate;
- either use `across(..)` as above or name the calculations, e.g., `summarize(volume_mu = mean(volume), pos_mu = mean(pos_prop), ...)`; and
- *I'm inferring*, but ... `mean(volume, pos_prop, neg_prop)` (with or without the `superbowl$`) is an error: in this case, the call is effectively `mean(volume, trim=pos_prop, na.rm=neg_prop)`, which should be producing errors. One *could* adapt this to be `mean(c(volume, pos_prop, neg_prop))` if you really want to aggregate three columns' data into a single number, but I thought that might be unintended over-aggregation.

Demonstration of this with real data:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(across(c(disp, mpg),
                   list(mu = ~ mean(.), sigma = ~ sd(.))))
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#     cyl disp_mu disp_sigma mpg_mu mpg_sigma
#   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     4    105.       26.9   26.7      4.51
# 2     6    183.       41.6   19.7      1.45
# 3     8    353.       67.8   15.1      2.56
```